# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol LIBID_

Tags: visual-studio-2012, com, mfc, atl

I am creating a ATL Com DLL .

During the link time I get the following error

dllmain.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol LIBID_ATLProject4Lib

Following are the files involved

## stdafx.h

```
#include "targetver.h"

#define _ATL_APARTMENT_THREADED

#define _ATL_NO_AUTOMATIC_NAMESPACE

#define _ATL_CSTRING_EXPLICIT_CONSTRUCTORS  // some CString constructors will be explicit


#define ATL_NO_ASSERT_ON_DESTROY_NONEXISTENT_WINDOW

#include "resource.h"

#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlctl.h>
#include <atlcom.h>
```

## ATLProject4.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include "ATLProject4_i.h"
#include "dllmain.h"


using namespace ATL;

class CAppModule : 
    public CComModule
{
};

// Used to determine whether the DLL can be unloaded by OLE.
STDAPI DllCanUnloadNow(void)
{
            return _AtlModule.DllCanUnloadNow();
    }

// Returns a class factory to create an object of the requested type.
STDAPI DllGetClassObject(_In_ REFCLSID rclsid, _In_ REFIID riid, _Outptr_ LPVOID* ppv)
{
        return _AtlModule.DllGetClassObject(rclsid, riid, ppv);
}

// DllRegisterServer - Adds entries to the system registry.
STDAPI DllRegisterServer(void)
{
    // registers object, typelib and all interfaces in typelib
    HRESULT hr = _AtlModule.DllRegisterServer();
        return hr;
}

// DllUnregisterServer - Removes entries from the system registry.
STDAPI DllUnregisterServer(void)
{
    HRESULT hr = _AtlModule.DllUnregisterServer();
        return hr;
}

// DllInstall - Adds/Removes entries to the system registry per user per machine.
STDAPI DllInstall(BOOL bInstall, _In_opt_  LPCWSTR pszCmdLine)
{
    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
    static const wchar_t szUserSwitch[] = L"user";

    if (pszCmdLine != NULL)
    {
        if (_wcsnicmp(pszCmdLine, szUserSwitch, _countof(szUserSwitch)) == 0)
        {
            ATL::AtlSetPerUserRegistration(true);
        }
    }

    if (bInstall)
    {   
        hr = DllRegisterServer();
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            DllUnregisterServer();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        hr = DllUnregisterServer();
    }

    return hr;
}
```

## dllmain.cpp

```
// dllmain.cpp : Implementation of DllMain.

   #include "stdafx.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include "ATLProject4_i.h"
#include "dllmain.h"

CATLProject4Module _AtlModule;

// DLL Entry Point
extern "C" BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    hInstance;
    return _AtlModule.DllMain(dwReason, lpReserved); 
}
```

Comment: What are the symbols that it is saying are multiply defined?

Comment: @user1793036 Now I am getting a different error

Comment: Create a new project using Project Wizard and then compare to your project.

Answer (score 1):

In exactly one source file, write `#define INITGUID` and then `#include "ATLProject4_i.h"`.

If I recall correctly, the wizard generates a file named `initguid.cpp` that contains just these two lines, and adds it to the project. You seem to be missing yours.

This is how it works. A MIDL-generated header file (typically, `IDLFileName_i.h`) contains a bunch of `DEFINE_GUID` invocations. `DEFINE_GUID` is a macro that expands to a global variable declaration (with `extern`) when `INITGUID` is not defined, and to a definition (without `extern`) when `INITGUID` is defined.

Comment: I am getting the error when I have the statement 
DECLARE_LIBID(LIBID_ATLProject4Lib)  in dllmain.h
If I comment this part , it links properly . But when I cannot register . I tried ur suggestion but it didnt work

Comment: Well I could register when I included #include "ATLProject4_i.c" in 
ATLProject4.cpp it did register .